# How to make a function that can have an optional period at the end to get data using js

Tags: javascript

Basically, if I were to make a function:

```js
function myFunction() {

}
```

How would I go about making it have a period at the end to get data such as `myFunction().amount`?

Comment: Have the function return an object.

Comment: yea returning an object in a function would be something like `function myFunction(){return {amount:1}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only objects use a period (dot) syntax to separate the object instance from the property or method that is being accessed on that object. For a function to use that syntax, you'd need an object to be returned from the function. One way to do that is to use the function as a constructor, which would cause it to be used to return an object instance and then you could access properties and/or methods of that object:

```js
function myFunction(){
  // Create a property that can be called
  this.foo = "bar";
}

// Create a method on the object's prototype,
// so that all instances can share the single
// implementation of the method
myFunction.prototype.baz = function(){
  console.log("Hello!");
};

// Now, make an instance of the object
let newObj = new myFunction();

// Call the property using dot notation
console.log(newObj.foo);

// Invoke the function using dot notation
newObj.baz();
```

If you need to be able to have syntax like this: `myFunction().somePropertyOrMethod`, then you need the function to return an object that you would then be calling properties or methods on like this:

```js
function myFunction(){
  // When you invoke myFunction, send
  // back an object with its own properties
  // and/or methods
  return {
    foo: "bar",
    baz: function(x){
      console.log(x);
    }
  }
}

// Here, the myFunction() part invokes
// the function, which causes the returned
// object to take it's place in the expression.
// Then, the .baz() part is accessing that object
// to invoke its method.
console.log(myFunction().foo);
myFunction().baz("Hello!");
```

Comment: For my project, I'm needing to have something that can be like myFunction().baz('value'). How would I do that? Like myFunction.prototype.baz = function(baz){ var x = baz; console.log(x) }; ?

Comment: @DabDatBass I'll update my answer with a second option that addresses that.

Comment: Could you also edit it so then it can work with DOM?

Comment: @DabDatBass Any function can work with the DOM, but there are many different ways to do that. You should post a different question for that.

Comment: Ok, so it should be working now but now the problem is that it doesn't console.log anything (see above code)

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
  return { amount: 20 };
};
```

Of course, replace the '20' with your value.